# find type implementing generic interface through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider a generic interface

```
public interface IA<T>
{
}
```

and two implementations

```
public class A1 : IA<string>
{}
public class A2 : IA<int>
{}
```

I want to write a method that finds the classes who implements `IA` interface with a specific type

```
public Type[] Find(IEnumerable<Type> types, Type type)
```

so that the following call

```
Find(new List<Type>{ typeof(A1), typeof(A2)}, typeof(string))
```

will return the type `A1`

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

I can assume that all the types passed in as the list will implement `IA` **however** not necessarily directly (For example `A1` can inherit from `BaseA` that implements `IA<string>`)

How can I accomplish this through reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MakeGenericType` to construct a specific generic type and check if it is available in the list of interfaces which the given class implements.

```
private static Type FindImplementation(IEnumerable<Type> implementations, Type expectedTypeParameter)
{
    Type genericIaType = typeof(IA<>).MakeGenericType(expectedTypeParameter);

    return implementations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(genericIaType));
}
```

And you call it like this

```
Type type = FindImplementation(new []{ typeof(A1), typeof(A2)}, typeof(string));
//Returns A1
```

Comment: `MakeGenericType` was indeed the missing piece for me. Thanks!